# Android - Vertical layout only

Tags: android

How do I make sure my app is only for vertical layout?

I have tried `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 178):

You need to add to all your activity not for one only. I think you understood that setting is per application wide, but it isn't.

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:label="My Activity"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Add the declaration to the activity tag in AndroidManifest for every Activity you want to be portrait-only.

Answer (score 21):

If you want some group of your activities to be locked on PORTRAIT mode only, than you can choose the next way:

```
public abstract class BasePortraitActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected final void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        performOnCreate(state);
    }

    protected abstract void performOnCreate(Bundle state);

}
```

And than just extend `BasePortraitActivity` where you need it. Or just add `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` to `YourActivity.onCreate()`.

Comment: To me, this line worked only after super.onCreate(SavedPreferances): setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

Answer (score 17):

you have to change into AndroidManifest.xml.

for each activity you have to insert:

```
android:configChanges = "orientation"

android:screenOrientation = "portrait"
```

for e.g.:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivityName"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:configChanges = "orientation"
                  android:screenOrientation = "portrait">
```

This works for a single activity.. But there seems no application wide setting there.

Answer (score 11):

In your manifest under activity add this :

```
<activity
        android:name="com.zeus.MyProject"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        >
```

Answer (score 4):

Activity is to block just in case want to block all and only repeat this line of code in their Activitys.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    // Here, talk to the java does not want that the user can rotate their activity.

    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

or open your "AndroidManisfest.xml" and add the rows for the portrait mode as shown below.

```
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` to the activity.

Answer (score 1):

Just to confirm Pentium10's answer.
I was having a similar issue and adding `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to the `activity` tag.
Did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

Put this attribute  in layout root:

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

It may help.