# Is there a way to keep the orientation of my droid project vertical?

Tags: android, layout, landscape

Can I set a code that doesn't change the orientation of the screen of my app if I turn the phone sideways?  I tried making a new main.xml file in the layout-land folder, and it just looks weird.

So, the screen doesn't turn when the oreintation is changed?

Thanks!

Comment: note ALL of the information in this post -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504064/android-vertical-layout-only (learn to accept and also what the search button does)

Comment: Keep in mind that there are many Android phones with keyboards that force the user into a landscape position. If there is anything on the page that requires text input, you should support a landscape orientation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
<Activity android:name="foo" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Comment: You should read this page http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html